# how to keep the precision when convert string to double value

Tags: python

For example .

```
s='[-97.173125220360362, -97.173125220360362]'
v=eval(s)
```

actually v =[-97.17312522036036, -97.17312522036036], lost the last 2. How can i keep the same value with the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('-97.173125220360362')
Decimal('-97.173125220360362')
```

For a string with list case use `str.split`, `str.strip` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> s = '[-97.173125220360362, -97.173125220360362]'
>>> [decimal.Decimal(x) for x in s.strip('[]').split(',')]
[Decimal('-97.173125220360362'), Decimal('-97.173125220360362')]
```

---

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

```
>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.dig
15
>>> s = '3.14159265358979'    # decimal string with 15 significant digits
>>> format(float(s), '.15g')  # convert to float and back -> same value
'3.14159265358979'
```

But for strings with more than `sys.float_info.dig` significant digits, this isn’t always true:

```
>>>
>>> s = '9876543211234567'    # 16 significant digits is too many!
>>> format(float(s), '.16g')  # conversion changes value
'9876543211234568'
```

So, if you want to maintain precision for floats that contain more than `sys.float_info.dig` digits use `decimal` module.

Comment: In this case - more a display issue... `format(float(their_string), '.17g'))` is fine...

Comment: I'm sorry actually i want to work on a list. That's why I use `eval`

Comment: @JonClements But what if the number of digits after decimal point are unknown for the list case?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
s = '[-97.173125220360362, -97.173125220360362]'
print ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Using `ast.literal_eval` is more safe than `eval`, as the docs mention.

This will give you a list of floats.

Comment: This give me much more precision than the string.

Comment: Either ordinary `float` values are good enough in which case no point using `Decimal`, or they're not in which case no point converting to `Decimal` after the value has been converted to a `float`.

Comment: @Samuel Ah, if you don't want that much, then you can just do `map(float, ast.literal_eval(s))`

Comment: @Haidro except if they're all defined as the above that `map` becomes redundant and you're left with `ast_literal` only...

Comment: @JonClements You are right my friend :). Come into Python chat why don't you :)

Comment: how to convert decimal list to a double list

Comment: @Samuel Double list? What do you mean?

Comment: @Haidro. Can i use the value directly in number operation

Comment: @Samuel Oh, I think I know what you're saying. Yes, because it isn't a string anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's more a display issue, to take your list, use [literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)instead:

```
from ast import literal_eval

s= '[-97.173125220360362, -97.173125220360362]'
items = literal_eval(s)
# [-97.17312522036036, -97.17312522036036]
```

Then to display, format appropriately:

```
as_strings = [format(el, '.17g') for el in items]
# ['-97.173125220360362', '-97.173125220360362']
```

Comment: I need to use the value, not just display

Comment: @Samuel then you just use the value.... You could display it as `3` and it still be `3.499912` - how it's displayed is different...

Comment: But the `eval` can give the same display with `literal_eval` in '.17g'

Comment: @Samuel I'm not quite sure what you mean, but `literal_eval` and `eval` do the same thing, except `literal_eval` only works on Python literals and is thus safer (eg `eval('2 + 2')` will give you 4, while `literal_eval` will give an error)